# Attach psycopg2 to python3.7

Tags: psycopg2, python-3.7, rhel7

My RHEL7 has Python 2.7. I installed python3.7 and also installed psycopg2. The issue is when I run the python3 script where psycopg2 module is used, I am getting error below:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

I cant figure out how to install/attach psycopg2 for python 3.

I tried reintalling pyscopg2. No luck!

Comment: On Linux Mint, I install python3-psycopg2.

Comment: No package python3-psycopg2 available.

Comment: Ok, so you installed the Python2 version of psycopg2. The Python3 has a different name and you have to find it, I am pretty sure it will be called python3 or some identifier to differentiate it from python2.

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying to find it. So far no luck. Many examples shows same command for Python3 as well.